# AS3 | Load image from URL and start drag issue

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I try to add image from URL address and start drag it when i click it, but i can't make drag function.

```
var url:String = 'http://www.helpexamples.com/flash/images/image1.jpg';
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loader_complete);
loader.load(urlRequest);
addChild(loader);

function loader_complete(evt:Event):void {
    var target_mc:Loader = evt.currentTarget.loader as Loader;
    target_mc.x = (stage.stageWidth - target_mc.width) / 2;
    target_mc.y = (stage.stageHeight - target_mc.height) / 2;
    target_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startDraging);
}

function startDraging(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var obj:MovieClip = e.target as MovieClip;
    obj.startDrag();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that in your complete function `loader_complete()` you set `target_mc` to a type `Loader`. Loaders do not have access `startDrag()` or `stopDrag()`.

What you can do is create a new `MovieClip` and add your loaded content to that `MovieClip`. So in your `loader_complete()`:

```
function loader_complete(evt:Event):void {
    var target_mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip(); //new movieclip
    target_mc.addChild( evt.target.content ); //add the content

    target_mc.x = (stage.stageWidth - target_mc.width) / 2;
    target_mc.y = (stage.stageHeight - target_mc.height) / 2;
    target_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startDraging);
    addChild( target_mc ); //add target_mc
}
```

Now your start drag should work.

Comment: Don't forget to do addChild of the target_mc. I'll add that into the answer.